# Alternate of rename() and remove() in C++

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-ce

I am trying to implement same functionality for File rename() and remove() for my winCE device.
but i guess the these function are not there in wince. as its there in cstdio header for C++.

Please suggest me the alternate for this.

Answer (score 4):

### Rename

`MoveFile`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365239(v=VS.85).aspx

### Remove

`DeleteFile`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

`#include <fstream>` contains std::remove() and std::rename().

Comment: its not fstream but rather cstdio